# Regular vs LALR(1): what is faster

Tags: regex, parsing, lalr

Supposing we have two grammars which define the same languge: regular one and LALR(1) one.

Both regular and LALR(1) algorithms are O(n) where n is input length.

Regexps are usually preferred for parsing regular languages. Why? Is there a formal proof (or maybe that's obvious) that they are faster?

Comment: If both are O(n) there you have your formal proof. They are asympthotically equivalent in terms of complexity.

Comment: Yes, but I'm more interested in practice than theory. Maybe lalr parser always has more states than regexp or smth of the kind. Or maybe they are simpler to understand. There must be a reason why regexps exist, if a wider class of languages (LR) can be parsed at O(n).

Comment: And yes, it is not a formal proof, for one algorithm can be 2*n  and another 3*n for instance: they both are O(n), but the first is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prefer stackless automaton over pushdown one as there is much more developed maths for regular language automatons.

We are able to perform determinization for both types of automaton, but we are **unable to perform efficient minimization of PDA**. The well known fact is that for every PDA there exists equivalent one with the only state. This means that we should minimize it with respect to transitions count/max stack depth/some other criteria.

Also the problem of checking whether two different PDAs are equivalent with respect to the language they recognize is undecidable.

Comment: Great! Could you provide a reference for the "well-known fact that for every PDA there exists equivalent one with a single state" and perhaps some links to papers on PDA minimization?

Comment: Well, here is the way of construction 2-state PDA from CFG: http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node35.html

Comment: Also you can construct CFG from PDA. All you need to construct equivalent 2-state PDA is to perform conversion PDA -> CFG -> PDA. Single state construction is mentioned by Hopcroft (search it by yourself :))

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between parsing and recognizing. Although you could build a regular-language parser, it would be extremely limited, since most useful languages are not parseable with a useful unambiguous regular grammar. However, most (if not all) regular expression libraries *recognize*, possibly with the addition of a finite number of "captures".

In any event, parsing really isn't the performance bottleneck anymore. IMHO, it's much better to use tools which demonstrably parse the language they appear to parse.

On the other hand, if all you want to do is recognize a language -- and the language happens to be regular -- regular expressions are a lot easier and require much less infrastructure (parser generators, special-purpose DSLs, slightly more complicated Makefiles, etc.)

(As an example of a language feature which is not regular, I give you: parentheses.)

Comment: 1) Well, to make myself clear, saying "regular expressions" I mean bare regular expressions (parsed with DFA), not any extensions used in regexp libraries. 2) "Parsing isn't bottleneck" -- depends on the kind of application. 3) About recognizing a language -- sometimes it's impossible without code execution (interpretation), e.g. obfuscated javascript. What I really wonder, can LALR(1) parser be more efficient than regexps.

Comment: @skvadnik, probably not, unless the regex library is written badly, in part because the LALR(1) parser is parsing. However, the LALR(1) parser can handle a larger variety of languages (such as ones with parentheses). I understood what you meant by regular expressions. I don't see why obfuscating javascript would make it any harder for an automated tool to recognize the language: "recognition" answers the question as to whether a string is syntactically correct; "parsing" provides you with the grammatical structure of the string.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by recognition. :) I meant "proof that this sentence belongs to this particular language".  I see that LR parsing is a more complex technique. Still I don't understand why it can't be faster for *regular* languages.

Comment: @skvadrik, fair enough, but I still don't see how obfuscation affects the process. It makes it more difficult for *me* to recognize the language, but clearly has no impact on parsing tools; otherwise, it would be somewhat counter-productive :)

Comment: Maybe lookahead for regular languge is too big so that it leads to much more states than for regexp parser...

Comment: Take a look at this popular example of obfuscated JS: http://badassjs.com/post/2929065287/obfuscation  I doubt that one can analyse it using regexps and proove it's JS. All that regexps can do is tokenize it into a stream of lexemes. And quite a lot of languages have such lexemes.

Comment: @skvadnik: You cannot prove that any javascript program is valid with only regexps because *regular expressions cannot recognize parentheses* (unless you limit the depth of parentheses, and even then it's a massive pain to write the regex).

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you, sorry. You said "f all you want to do is recognize a language, regular expressions are a lot easier and require much less infrastructure " --- I thought you were for regexps as a tool for recognizing. :)

Comment: @skvadnik: that's true, it was misleading. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

People prefer regular expressions because they're easier to write. If your language is a regular language, why bother creating a CFG grammer for it?

Comment: Maybe CFG (and LALR(1) or SLR in particular) parser is/can be more efficient than regexps. If so, many people would prefer more complex but also more effective approach.